# Мировая закулиса

Tags: фразеология

Выражение "мировая закулиса" в наше время уже устарело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, выражение цветёт и пахнет. Другое дело, что мировой закулисы по всей видимости никогда не существовало, и вряд ли она появится, но вера в неё сродни религиозному чувству, поэтому людей в это верущих стараюсь лишний раз не трогать.

По поводу мировой закулисы понравилось высказывание нынешнего министра иностранных дел России С. В. Лаврова, за точность цитаты не ручаюсь, воспроизвожу по памяти из выпуска новостей примерно пятилетней давности, но смысл верный:

> Мировой закулисы, к сожалению не существует. Почему "к сожалению"? Потому что если бы она была, то за любую кулису можно было бы зайти и договориться с одним человеком или даже организацией. А так как её нет, то приходится договариваться со всеми, а это намного трудней.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Закрывать глаза на очевидное удобнее всего. Только давайте не будем уподобляться страусам - это плохо кончается. И советую почитать:  
http://www.contrtv.ru/common/1898/

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, только из уважения к вам прочитал ссылку и отвечаю. Автор статьи все свои аргументы за существование "мировой закулисы" приводит в последнем абзаце и они настолько ничего не доказывают,что их даже разбирать глупо.

В остальной части статьи автор доказывает, что мировой заговор в принципе возможен. Ну да, мировой заговор в принципе возможен, если все конкурирующие между собой сильные мира сего смогут поделить мир так, чтобы никто не остался в накладе. А вот в это что-то не верится, слишком сильнопересекающиеся у них сферы влияния.

Comment: Но допустим они смогли объединиться, тогда возникает вопрос - во имя чего они поступились своими личными интересами? Религия? Идеология? Нация? Так как клика у нас общемировая, то нация (прощай, "жидомасоны") и религия отпадает, остаётся идеология, но какая? Неизвестна. Притом, что вся эта структура умудрилась ни разу не спалиться и не породить своего "Сноудена".

P.S. @Fuchoin Kazuki, в юности мне нравились споры на религиозные темы, но сейчас подобные разговоры меня скорее тяготят, так что надеюсь обсуждать их не придётся.

Answer (score 2):

А  почему  теневой  кабинет  назвали  закулисой ( даже  если  весь  мир -  театр ), там  ведь  актёры  ждут  выхода,  рабочие  сцены,  помреж  сидит,  пожарник  дежурит.  Все,  что  происходит  на  сцене,  решается  не  за  кулисами.  Вот  свары  и  козни,  не  планируемые  режиссёром,  там  могут  иметь  место.  Выходит,  что  мировая  закулиса  -  это  образ  непрогнозируемых  проявлений  в  мировой  политике.  А  просто  "закулиса",  не  мировая,  а  театральная  -  есть ?  Как  явление  театральной  жизни,  конечно,  а  не  как  часть  сценического  пространства.

Answer (score 1):

"Теневой кабинет" назвали мировой закулисой, потому что судьбы мира (якобы) решаются втайне от большей части человечества, не у него на виду, а скрытно, как бы за кулисами... Театральной закулисы нет, то есть нет выражения "театральная закулиса". А вот театральное или цирковое закулисье есть. ЗАКУЛИСЬЕ я, ср. coulisse f. 1. Закулисное пространство цирка, театра. "Гоп, трясущийся от негодования (столкнулся с коверным), прихрамывая, втащил в закулисье моноцикл." М. Шарапова Коверный. // Октябрь 1998 3 24. "Она (наездница) не замечала ничего вокруг; ни моего в упор взгляда, ни суеты закулисья." М. Шарпова Как крылья бабочки. // ЛУ 1996 4 101. "Холод и пот закулисья." Е. Скульская Однокрылый рояль. // ДН 1998 8 115

Comment: Значит  выражение   есть,  но  в  несколько  иной  форме,  и  с  другим  значением,  чем  закулиса ( мировая ).  Стало  быть  "мировая  закулиса" - идиома.  Понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Об актуальности идиомы.

> Если вы занимаетесь золотом, вы знаете всё это наверняка, потому что
>   торговля XAU - одна из тех профессиональных кочек, откуда **закулисная
>   мировая** механика видна безошибочно и точно.

Из пиратской электронной версии романа В.Пелевина 2016 года.
Пелевин, я так полагаю, претендует на актуальность и современность в каждом своём романе.

Comment: Спасибо, Una Nana!